# How has this Perl script been invoked?

Tags: linux, perl

I'd like to know inside a Linux Perl script whether it has been invoked from cmd line or a bash script. Any Idea?

Comment: Not really possible. But what is your actual problem you are trying to solve by detecting how the program was invoked? If you are trying to find out whether STDOUT goes directly to a terminal or to something else like a pipe or file, then that can be discovered in most cases.

Comment: Why do you want to check this? This seems like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In all cases I can think of your approach is fragile.

Comment: @rightfold without the X

Comment: Well, if it's being invoked by a specific shell script (cron) it should send an eMail but if it's being invoked by the command line not.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the linux command 'id' and redirect the output to a log file this way you will always know who invoked the script.

Comment: Isn't it the same output whether I use the cmd line or the cron? Thanks

Comment: OK, at the moment I'm using an option as argument, but I thought  it'd be fine if there was a special variable to check for. Actually, it doesn't look like there is one. Thanks anyway

Comment: It depends, if the cron job was satrted in your user's crontab then it will be.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the process id of the Perl script's parent process with [`getppid`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#getppid). Then you can parse `ps` output or examine the `/proc/<parent-pid>` virtual file system to identify the parent.

---

**Update**: for your specific problem, wanting your Perl script to do something special if it was invoked by a certain bash script, it might be easier to set a special environment variable in the script. For example:

```
# special bash script
export SPECIAL=1
perl my_script.pl



# my_script.pl
...
do_something();
if ($ENV{SPECIAL}) {
    print "Called from the special bash script\n";
    send_email();
} else {
    print "Not called from special bash script\n";
}
```